# Magento 2 Check if Shipping Method title is abc add some Text

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am working On Shipping Methods where I want to display text as per the shipping method Title. I got the file methods.html file and there are display shipping methods by Knockout js.

Now I want to check if the shipping title is ABC then it displays some text else some other text but I don't have an idea how to check shipping title with knockout js.

Please let me know if anyone has idea about it.